Reference Needed: Existence of Subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with Specified Lower and Upper Asymptotic Densities
Could someone point me to a book or paper that states the following fact:
For any $ 0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq 1 $, there exists a subset $ A \subset \mathbb{N} $ such that
$$\underline{\mathrm{d}}(A) = \alpha \quad \text{and} \quad \overline{\mathrm{d}}(A) = \beta, $$
where
$$
\underline{\mathrm{d}}(A)=\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{card}[A \cap[1,2, \cdots, n]], \quad \overline{\mathrm{d}}(A)=\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{card}[A \cap[1,2, \cdots, n]]
$$
Thanks in advance!

I suggest that you add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

If $n_k$ is a sufficiently rapidly increasing sequence and you alternate between choosing $\alpha$-dense and $\beta$-dense subsets in $[n_k, n_{k+1}]\cap\mathbb{N}$, your resulting set will have these properties.
